# Multiple dropdown click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I have a backbone.js app that looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/TD9Wj/.

If I use the default code for [Dropit.js](http://dev7studios.com/dropit/), everything works fine. But I'm trying to get the code to close on clicking on the trigger. So when you click on "menu", the dropdown should close.

So I used a pull request update to the code (https://github.com/gilbitron/Dropit/pull/5/files)

It changes:

```
if($(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).hasClass('dropit-open')) return false;
```

to:

```
if($(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).hasClass('dropit-open')) {
   $('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
   return false;
}
```

This allows me to click on the "menu" trigger and the dropdown will close. Unfortunately, when I do this, if I have multiple StoreProductViews open, only the first one added will have the DropIt menu functioning.

Comment: you mean multiple dropdown is opening ? When you want to close dropdown?

Comment: No I mean when I render multiple templates (and there is a dropdown menu inside each template) that only the first template rendered has a menu that shows up, the others don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your issue is caused due to multiple event binding.
In other words, each time you render an instance of the `StoreProductView`, you apply the `.dropit()` method to all the `.menu` items on the page.

Consider making the following changes in your code:

1. Change `$('.menu').dropit();` (line 71) to `this.$('.menu').dropit();` or `this.$el.find('.menu').dropit();` (should be the same, just a different syntax). This will make the view look for the `.menu` element that is contained by it, and not to look in the whole document.
2. The above change is not enough, as the element for all the `StoreProductView` is the same, so the following will be necessary too. Instead of using:

   `var storeProductView = new StoreProductView({
       el: $('#widgets')
   });`

   Try to do something like:

   `var storeProductView = new StoreProductView();
   $('#widgets').append(storeProductView.$el);`

Hope it helps, please ask if something is not clear.